# RemoveAllViews no funciona

Tags: android, android-studio

Que tal, tengo una aplicación android en la cual necesito usar un tablelayout para buscar productos, todo funciona bien al buscar el primer producto, pero cuando busco un segundo producto no se quitan las filas y etiquetas del primero, ya coloqué el removeAllViews pero no funciona, quizás lo estoy colocando mal o no sé que pueda estar pasando, les dejo el fragmento de código y ojalá alguien pueda orientarme:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


       // listaProd.setAdapter(result);
        tl  = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.miTableLayout);
        tl.removeAllViews();

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFecha=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutMuestra=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutResultado=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        filas =new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        filas.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);


        cabeceraCantidad = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        cabeceraTienda = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        cabeceraEstilo = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        cabeceraTienda.setText("Tienda");
        cabeceraTienda.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);
        cabeceraTienda.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        cabeceraCantidad.setText("Total");
        cabeceraCantidad.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        cabeceraCantidad.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);

        cabeceraEstilo.setText("Nombre del Producto");
        cabeceraEstilo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        cabeceraEstilo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);

        filas.addView(cabeceraTienda);
        filas.addView(cabeceraCantidad);
        filas.addView(cabeceraEstilo);

        //tvTiendas = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tl.addView(filas);
            for(int m = 0; m < listaCabecera.size()-1; m++)
            {
                cabeceraTallas = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                for(int n = m+1; n < listaCabecera.size(); n++)
                {
                    if (cabeceraTallas.getParent() != null)
                    {
                        ((ViewGroup) cabeceraTallas.getParent()).removeView(cabeceraTallas);
                    }


                    if(listaCabecera.get(m).getTalla().equals(listaCabecera.get(n).getTalla()))
                    {
                        m++;
                    }
                    else {
                        cabeceraTallas.setText(listaCabecera.get(m).getTalla());
                        cabeceraTallas.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        cabeceraTallas.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera);
                        filas.addView(cabeceraTallas);
                    }

                }
            }

        for(int k =0 ; k < listaCabecera.size()-1; k++)
            {

                filasdatos =new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                filasdatos.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

                filasCantidad = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                filasCantidad.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);
                //filasdatos.removeAllViews();

                tvTiendas = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tvTotal  = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                totali = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tvEstilo = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                for(int l = k+1; l < listaCabecera.size(); l++)
                {
                    if (tvTiendas.getParent() != null
                            || tvTotal.getParent() != null
                            || tvEstilo.getParent() != null)
                    {
                        ((ViewGroup) tvTiendas.getParent()).removeView(tvTiendas);
                        ((ViewGroup) tvTotal.getParent()).removeView(tvTotal);
                        ((ViewGroup) tvEstilo.getParent()).removeView(tvEstilo);
                    }

                    if(listaCabecera.get(k).getTienda().equals(listaCabecera.get(l).getTienda())) {
                        k++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tvTiendas.setText(listaCabecera.get(k).getTienda());
                        tvTotal.setText(listaCabecera.get(k).getCantidad());
                        tvEstilo.setText(listaCabecera.get(k).getNombre_Producto());

                        sumaTotal =Integer.parseInt(tvTotal.getText().toString());
                        total += sumaTotal;

                        tvTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));

                        tvTiendas.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tvTiendas.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);

                        tvTotal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tvTotal.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);

                        tvEstilo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tvEstilo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);

                        filasdatos.addView(tvTiendas);

                        filasdatos.addView(tvTotal);
                        filasdatos.addView(tvEstilo);
                    }

                }



                tl.addView(filasdatos);



                for(int z = 0; z < listaCabecera.size(); z++)
                {
                    tvCantidad = new TextView(getApplicationContext());


                        if (tvCantidad.getParent() != null)
                        {
                            ((ViewGroup) tvCantidad.getParent()).removeView(tvCantidad);

                        }

                        if(tvTiendas.getText().equals(listaCabecera.get(z).getTienda())) {
                            tvCantidad.setText(listaCabecera.get(z).getCantidad());

                            tvCantidad.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tvCantidad.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda);
                            filasdatos.addView(tvCantidad);
                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola Sandra agregué una respuesta comenta si te es de ayuda! =)

Answer (score 1):

revisando tu código,  estas tomando la referencia del `TableLayout` de nuevo y quieres eliminar las vistas que contiene:

```
    tl  = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.miTableLayout);
    tl.removeAllViews();
```

No obtengas nuevamente la referencia y trates de eliminarle las vistas, toma la instancia actual:

```
    //tl  = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.miTableLayout);
    tl.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no funciona :(

Comment: Debe funcionar, estas eliminando las vistas al inicio de onPostExecute() , agrega el removeAllViews() al final  y comenta que resultado tienes.

Comment: Tampoco, si lo pongo al final no me muestra la tabla, y es que antes sí funcionaba pero luego le agregué ciclos for para acomodar los textview y ya no funcionó, quité los ciclos y nada :(, no sé qué pueda estar pasando.